# Setup Elasticsearch service on my react native app

Tags: node.js, react-native, elasticsearch

I have a free trial of elasticsearch service and I want to use it for my react native project.

I followed the instructions from this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-getting-started-node-js.html) on how to ingest data with node.js on elastic search service. From the instructions seems pretty easy - I need to install @elastic/elasticsearch package and then connect with it using the correct credentials. This example is from the official elastic search page:

```
const { Client } = require('@elastic/elasticsearch')
const config = require('config');
const elasticConfig = config.get('elastic');

const client = new Client({
  cloud: {
    id: elasticConfig.cloudID
  },
  auth: {
    username: elasticConfig.username,
    password: elasticConfig.password
  }
})
```

I installed the package and copy-pasted the above code into my project, then try to run my app with Expo. However, my app doesn't build. It constantly gives me errors from the type:

> The package at "node_modules/@elastic/transport/lib/Transport.js"
> attempted to import the Node standard library module "zlib". It failed
> because the native React runtime does not include the Node standard
> library.

So I thought maybe I need to install `zlib` library. I did so and then on the next rebuild I got the same error but with different packages (`os`, then `events`, `path` and so on). Every time I stop the build, and then install a new missing package.  The last such error was with the package `http`. I installed it and then run my project again, but I got the same error:

```
The package at "node_modules/@elastic/transport/lib/connection/HttpConnection.js" attempted to import the Node standard library module "http".
It failed because the native React runtime does not include the Node standard library.
```

(even though I just installed it with `npm install http`).

My question is what I am doing wrong? Why I can not set up a simple elastic search connection? I am running my project with `Expo`, if thats important.

Comment: Looks to me as if you are using an incompatible version of node.